# Saving State With Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that will never require more than one instance of an activity.  I want it so that when the user comes back to a screen it is in the same state as they left it except for a few places where it doesn't make sense.  I've worked out saving the persisted data with onpause onstop updates.  However to keep the screen looking the way it did when they left it i use intents specifically setting the flags to Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP then startActivity. It seems to work great but does it make sense?  Is there a smarter way?  Pitfalls doing it this way etc... any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:launchMode = "singleTask"
```

add the above line for every activity in the manifeast file. Adding these launch relaunch the activity instead of creating the activity again.

Refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)